# Google Apps Script: Trigger deletes a value placed from Google Forms and notifies the user due to a duplicate in the Spreadsheet through setNote()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently making a script in Google Apps Script where the trigger deletes a value placed from Google Forms and notifies the user that the value was deleted due to a duplicate in the Spreadsheet through setNote().

I have tried using a modal popup but apparently it does not work for triggers. Any way around this or am I doing something wrong with the setNote() function? I am always getting a TypeError from it.

```
function DuplicatePatient() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 2, lastrow, 1).getValues();
  values = values.flat();
  values.pop();
  // just to visualize the results:
  console.log(values);
  var columnB = ["B"];
  var patient = ss.getRange(columnB + lastrow);
  var triggerPatient = patient.getValue();
  var duplicateRow = 1 + values.indexOf(triggerPatient);
  var setNoteDestination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(duplicateRow, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  var setNote1Destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastrow, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
  var timestamp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(duplicateRow, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
      timestampFlat = timestamp.flat();
      Logger.log(timestampFlat)
  if (duplicateRow > 0){
    ss.deleteRow(lastrow);
    setNoteDestination.setNote("⚠️ Duplicate found on row "+ duplicateRow +" The input was recorded on "+timestamp),
    setNote1Destination.setNote("⚠️ Duplicate found on row "+ duplicateRow +" The input was recorded on "+timestamp)   
  }
}
```

Comment: About `I am always getting a TypeError from it.`, I think that the reason for this issue is due to that the values of `setNoteDestination` and `setNote1Destination` are not Class Range objects. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected goal. By this, I cannot propose an answer. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hello! the goal of my script is to notify the user when there are duplicates in the column of names. With this, I have tried using a pop up modal but apparently it does not work when being called from a trigger. So I opted to use the setNote() function for the notification part. I wanted it to be called out on a trigger where it marks the setNoteDestination and setNoteDestination1 with a mark to indicate that both of them are duplicates and it erases the newly added input from Forms.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, what is `the column of names`? And, I cannot understand `setNoteDestination` and `setNote1Destination`. I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: You dont have to apologize for anything! here is what the spreadsheet looks like. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rD-qxZoiRRfbIX8MqSnqJAiTm7_i4TeyI9TnjOeyQtM/edit?usp=sharing
setNoteDestination is the cell of the duplicate value found while setNoteDestination1 is the current added value from the forms which is in the last row. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I open it, it seems that the Spreadsheet is not shared. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Now, I could open your sample Spreadsheet. Thank you for it. About your goal, I would like to confirm whether my understanding is correct. In your goal, you want to check the values of column "B" of the last row and column "B" of other rows except for the last row. And, when the duplicate rows of them are existing, you want to set the note to the last row and other duplicated rows. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: exactly that. If we could set notes to multiple duplicate rows set on trigger that would be amazing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Now, I noticed that the value of `timestamp` is not correct. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the values of column "B" of the last row and column "B" of other rows except for the last row.
- When the duplicate rows of them are existing, you want to set the note to the last row and other duplicated rows.

In your script, the values of `setNoteDestination` and `setNote1Destination` are not Class Range objects. By this, an error occurs at `setNoteDestination.setNote(,,,)`. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function DuplicatePatient() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastRow);
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var search = values.pop();
  var { ranges, rows } = values.reduce((o, [, b], i) => {
    if (b == search[1]) {
      o.ranges.push(`B${i + 2}`);
      o.rows.push(i + 2);
    }
    return o;
  }, { ranges: [], rows: [] });
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  // range.clearNote(); // If you want to clear Notes, please use this line.
  ranges.push(`B${lastRow}`);
  rows.push(lastRow);
  var timestamp = search[0];
  var note = "⚠️ Duplicate found on row " + rows.join(",") + " The input was recorded on " + timestamp;
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setNote(note);
}
```

- When this script is run, the duplicated values are checked from column "B". The value of the last row is used as the search value. When the duplicated values are found, the value of `note` is set to column "B" of the rows.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: @Dean Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.